# How to show a throbber or other indicator during an ajax operation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, loader

I would like to know how to show an [ajax loader gif](http://ajaxload.info/) while the "remote" function is busy with backend procedures.

If possible, could you please look at the [milk example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) and tell me how it would fit into that code. Simply click on "Show script used on this page" to view the source.

Thanks

Comment: What's the relation of your question title to your question?

Comment: I didn't name it that, someone else must have renamed it, because no where in my question did I mention anything about ajax, I specifically said look at the milk example which uses "remote" not ajax.

Comment: @Ash My comment was about your original title of _Remember the Milk_ which doesn't contain any information about your specific question. I'm not sure if @bmargulies' title edit is correct for your situation, but it's certainly more descriptive.

Comment: Actually, I didn't name it something with Remember the milk... So one of you guys must've changed it - don't blame me for your staff stupidity...

Comment: @Ash, [check it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5735875/revisions).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already know how to AJAX. The basic procedure is that at the beginning of the operation you show an image, and at the end when you get results back from the server you hide it.

```
<!--html-->
<img id='ajaxLoader' src='mahAjaxLoader.gif' />
<!--has display:none via CSS-->
```

-

```
//js
function doAjaxStuff() {
    $('#ajaxLoader').toggle(); //toggle visibility; it's now shown

    //other stuff

    $.ajax({
        //normal AJAX stuff
        onComplete : function() {
            $('#ajaxLoader').toggle(); //it's hidden again
            //other oncomplete stuff
    });
}
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Edit: The [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) method accepts an object literal like the ajax request does. So plug this in:

```
remote : {
    beforeSend : function() {
        $('#ajaxLoader').toggle();
    }
    onComplete : function() {
        $('#ajaxLoader').toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you found an ajax call on the milk example page that I referenced in my question... it's using "remote" method?

Comment: @Ash - `remote` is an alias for `$.ajax()`. The term AJAX means "Asychronous Javascript and XML." While XML has become an archaic protocol under most circumstances, nearly any call that Javascript makes to a server is, in fact, AJAX. That is where everyone is getting it.

Answer (score 1):

For your AJAX call:

```
var GetWSDataJSON = function (ServiceUrl, Parameters, onSuccess, onFailure, onComplete){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "{" + Parameters + "}",
        url: basePath + ServiceUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var msg = result.d;
            onSuccess(msg);
        },
        error: function (request, status, throwerror) {
            onFailure();
        },
        complete: function () {
            if (onComplete != undefined) {
            onComplete();
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Then, in your actual AJAX request:

```
function SomeFunctionHere() {
    $('#containerDiv').showLoading();
    GetWSDataJSON('WebServices/Service.asmx/GetYourData', 'someData: "' + someVar + '"', SomeFunction_Success, SomeFunction_Failure, SomeFunctionComplete);
}
```

Finally, your functions for after the AJAX call:

```
var SomeFunction_Success = function(msg){ //do something with the msg }
var SomeFunction_Failure = function(){ //do something with the error }
var SomeFunction_Complete = function(){ $('#containerDiv').hideLoading(); }
```

Comment: I did... sorry, that was a colossal mess. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you found an ajax call on the milk example page that I referenced in my question...

Answer (score 1):

I took this from the page you created. For simplistic sake I put it all as js but you can create the element with html and apply the styles in the style sheet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signupwrap").prepend("<div id='ajax_loader'><img src='path_to_image' /></div>");
    $("#ajax_loader").css({
        width: $("#signupwrap").width(),
        height: $("#signupwrap").height()
    }).hide();

    $("#ajax_loader img").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top:"300px" //or wherever you want to put it
        left:"50%",
        marginLeft:$(".ajax_loader img").width()/2
    });
});


submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
    var dataObj = "sdfsd" // get all the values and build the ajax data object
    $("#ajax_loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"your_url",
        data: dataObj,
        success:function(val){
            $("#ajax_loader").hide();

        };
    });
},
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you found an ajax call on the milk example page that I referenced in my question... It's using "remote" method?